# JSON array serialization issue after spring-cloud-stream update

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I use `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka` to connect to the kafka broker

I updated spring-cloud-dependencies version to **2021.0.1**

I went from this

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka:jar:3.0.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core:jar:3.0.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:jar:3.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:2.5.11.RELEASE:compile
```

To this

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:jar:5.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:2.8.4:compile
```

Before the update everything worked fine, I consume JSON array message (`[{}]`) from topic (each message is an JSON array) and using ObjectMapper I convert `Message<String>` to a POJO List

```
  @Bean
  public Function<Message<String>, Message<Map<String, Object>>> process(HandleMessage handleMessage) {
    return message -> handleMessage.onMessage(message);
  }
```

But now after the update when it try to consume messages I got these exceptions :

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class java.lang.String to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer specified in value.serializer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class [B (java.lang.String and [B are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer specified in value.serializer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable cannot be cast to class [B (reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; [B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

There the complete stacktrace :

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ProducerConfigurationMessageHandler@8ff35b3]; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class java.lang.String to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer specified in value.serializer
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:65)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:457)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:325)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:268)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:232)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:222)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:457)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:325)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:268)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:232)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:222)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.ErrorMessagePublisher.publish(ErrorMessagePublisher.java:168)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer.recover(ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer.java:83)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.handleRetryExhausted(RetryTemplate.java:539)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:387)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:255)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2629)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2609)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2536)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2427)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2305)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1979)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1364)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1355)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1247)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class java.lang.String to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer specified in value.serializer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:904)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:861)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:993)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:649)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:429)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:513)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:136)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class [B (java.lang.String and [B are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer.serialize(ByteArraySerializer.java:19)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:901)
    ... 69 common frames omitted

2022-04-20 04:36:34.107 ERROR 28644 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ProducerConfigurationMessageHandler@518e5340]; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer specified in value.serializer, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=FluxMapFuseable, headers={aeg-delivery-count=[B@86b720c, aeg-event-type=[B@371ebea0, deliveryAttempt=3, aeg-output-event-id=[B@5b6b16cc, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedTopic=deposit-assets, target-protocol=kafka, aeg-metadata-version=[B@76375b3f, kafka_offset=7813, aeg-subscription-name=[B@259fbce7, scst_nativeHeadersPresent=true, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@a629a5c, aeg-data-version=[B@6736ed4a, id=09a642f8-1a9b-0ce1-f8a9-331038295adc, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1650429388041, contentType=application/json, app.name=[B@64684a16, kafka_groupId=foo, timestamp=1650429391672}]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:65)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractDestinationResolvingMessagingTemplate.send(AbstractDestinationResolvingMessagingTemplate.java:72)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1.doSendMessage(FunctionConfiguration.java:619)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1.handleMessageInternal(FunctionConfiguration.java:602)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:216)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.sendMessageIfAny(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:397)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$300(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:454)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:428)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.lambda$onMessage$0(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:255)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2629)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2609)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2536)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2427)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2305)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1979)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1364)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1355)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1247)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer specified in value.serializer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:904)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:861)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:993)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:649)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:429)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:513)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:136)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable cannot be cast to class [B (reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; [B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer.serialize(ByteArraySerializer.java:19)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:901)
    ... 54 more
```

I have checked some Spring Cloud code source and especially this class `org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry` and i have found out that this method is added `fluxifyInputIfNecessary`, I guess some streaming is happening, the message is converted to be send as an `FluxMapFuseable`

and why the `process` function is not even called ? because the error is occuring in the producer level

So any idea to how solve this problem ?

ConsumerConfig values:

```
allow.auto.create.topics = true
auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
auto.offset.reset = latest
bootstrap.servers = [foo-server:9093]
check.crcs = true
client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
client.id = consumer-null-4
client.rack = 
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
enable.auto.commit = true
exclude.internal.topics = true
fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
group.id = null
group.instance.id = null
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
interceptor.classes = []
internal.leave.group.on.close = true
internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
isolation.level = read_uncommitted
key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
max.poll.records = 500
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor, class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CooperativeStickyAssignor]
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 30000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.login.class = null
sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
sasl.mechanism = PLAIN
security.protocol = SASL_SSL
security.providers = null
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
session.timeout.ms = 45000
socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
ssl.engine.factory.class = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
ssl.keystore.key = null
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.certificates = null
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
```

ProducerConfig values:

```
acks = 1
batch.size = 16384
bootstrap.servers = [foo-server:9093]
buffer.memory = 33554432
client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
client.id = producer-1
compression.type = none
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
enable.idempotence = false
interceptor.classes = []
key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
linger.ms = 0
max.block.ms = 60000
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
max.request.size = 1048576
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 30000
retries = 2147483647
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.login.class = null
sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
sasl.mechanism = PLAIN
security.protocol = SASL_SSL
security.providers = null
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
ssl.engine.factory.class = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
ssl.keystore.key = null
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.certificates = null
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
transactional.id = null
value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
```

Comment: Are you by any chance using Java 8 ? The stack trace is a typical version mismatch that occurs during reflection.

Comment: Still don't understand why you are using `Message<string>` instead of `Message<Byte[]>`? Can you share code that translates messages payloads in your solution?

Comment: @AdamWaldenberg nop i'm using java 11

Comment: @ymz down In `process` function I use ObjectMapper to convert a string to my POJO List

Comment: my question is: can you share code that pass message to `process` function? I would like to verify the way you consume messages from broker in order to better understand why messages are translated as strings